# View JSON API value on php file

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to create a php script to display only the "credit" value of the account 491027679-102 but it does not work, I get a white screen. Can you help me solve this problem?

This is the script I did, where I drew?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.vohippo.com/it/vohippo/user/ApiWhsGetSubList?email=mail@example.com&apikey=123'; 
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$apiResult = json_decode($content);

($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') && 
  trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
  return $item['account'] === '491027679-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

echo $account[0]['credit'];
?>
```

Comment: I think we would need to see the JSON string or a `print_r($account);`

Comment: `print_r($account);` returns error 500

Comment: THen the JSON String! As obviously the code is not creating `$account` as you may have hoped

Comment: I changed the four string like this: `$apiResult = json_decode($content);` . This is the result of print_r: `Array ( [1] => Array ( [account] => 491027679-102 [name] => test2 [channels] => 15 [server] => sip.vohippo.com [billing] => 0 [billingstep] => 60 [increment] => 0 [credit] => 0.0000 ) )` but the credit value does not come out

Comment: The index of `credit` is in parent array which has an index of `1`. And in your code you are using index [0]. Changing it to `$account[1]['credit'];` will give you the correct answer.

Comment: Is there a way to remove `[1]` and leave only the account id as an identifier? So that it is enough to change `$item ['account'] === '491027679-102';` to see the related credit

Comment: Oh hi, Mark. I suggest you don't leave your API key open like that, it's not very safe. Actually, I suggest you get a new one if possible, since it will stay in the edit history, idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already know the index of the parent array for the `credit`, you can do it as above `echo $account[0]['credit'];`.

If you don't know the index of the parent and it changes everytime in the `$account` variable, you should loop through the array.

Instead of using `echo $account[0]['credit'];`, you should loop through the array:

```
foreach ($account as $key => $value) {
    echo $account[$key]['credit'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script:

```php
<?php

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390848/view-json-api-value-on-php-file

$url = 'https://www.vohippo.com/it/vohippo/user/ApiWhsGetSubList?email=webmasterlertux@gmail.com&apikey=4c62479846b0aea59ac007f3a283b581';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$apiResult = json_decode($content);

($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') && trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
  return $item['account'] === '491027679-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

echo $account[0]['credit'];
?>
```

My php version:

```
php-fpm at 87a5be43419e in /var/www/html 
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.4 (cli) (built: Apr  5 2018 00:37:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

Running your script:

```
$ php question-54390848.php 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /var/www/html/question-54390848.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/question-54390848.php on line 9
```

The error is in line 9 because you try to access an array when you an object, because in line 7 `json_decode($content)` gives you an object, but to get an array you need to do `json_decode($content, true).

Lets' fix it:

```php
<?php

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54390848/view-json-api-value-on-php-file

$url = 'https://www.vohippo.com/it/vohippo/user/ApiWhsGetSubList?email=webmasterlertux@gmail.com&apikey=4c62479846b0aea59ac007f3a283b581';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

// Adding `true` to enable decoding to an array
$apiResult = json_decode($content, true);

($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') && trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

$account = [];

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
  return $item['account'] === '491027679-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

// using array_filter will return the array entries as they have been matched,
// thus your match happens in the array entry with key `1`, but you try to
// access the entry `0` in the echo statement.
// so using array_values will return all values in the array indexed from key `0`.
$account = array_values($account);

echo $account[0]['credit'];
?>
```

Another fix was needed in order you can access the `$account[0]` in your echo statement. Please read the comments in the code.

Running your script again:

```
php-fpm at 87a5be43419e in /var/www/html 
$ php question-54390848.php
0.0000
```

**NOTE**: Your script needs to have more checks for errors with the response and when accessing the `$account` array.

## SECURITY ALERT

You have published the **API KEY** in your question:

```
$url = 'https://www.vohippo.com/it/vohippo/user/ApiWhsGetSubList?email=webmasterlertux@gmail.com&apikey=4c62479846b0aea59ac007f3a283b581';
```

Now everyone can access this service in your behalf and if is a paid one you will be the one paying the bill.

**Please reset this API KEY immediately and get a new one**

API KEYS best practice is to be sent in the header